# Riemann Hypothesis Polar Coordinate System

Tags: number-theory

[image]

In the above linked graph: can someone explain to me what the 1, 10, 6, 14, 8 ,18 are? The one's with the double arrow.

Yours very truly,

Vibegenerator

Comment: What is it ? It looks like the partial sums of $\frac1{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ or something similar

Comment: Please tell us where this comes from because knowing this could help us to answer your question as it would give us more context such as why it was created, how it's being used, etc. Thanks.